# Why connecting React app to graphql gives "Error : NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource." error?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

I am trying to connect to local setup of graphql with react.

This is my graphql version
`"graphql": "^15.8.0",`
Here is `server.js`

```js
const express = require('express');
const expressGraphQL = require('express-graphql').graphqlHTTP;
const schema = require('./schema/schema');

const app = express();

app.use('/graphql', expressGraphQL({
    schema,
    graphiql: true
}));

app.listen(4000, () => {
    console.log('Listening');
});
```

This works fine and I am able to connect to graphiql ui.

Here is react app and dependencies.

```
    "@apollo/client": "^3.7.12",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "graphql": "^16.6.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
```

React app connection:

```js
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache } from '@apollo/client';

export const client = new ApolloClient({
    uri: 'http://localhost:4000/graphql',
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});
```

And here is `index.js`

```js
import './index.css';
import { ApolloProvider } from '@apollo/client';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import {client} from "./apollo";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
      <ApolloProvider client={client}>
          <App />
      </ApolloProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

And here is `App.js`

```js
import { useQuery, gql } from '@apollo/client';
import {GET_USERS} from "./apollo/queries";

function App() {
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_USERS);
  if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
  if (error) return <p>Error : {error.message}</p>;
  console.log(data)
  return (
    <div className="App">
    </div>
  );
}
```

It gives me this error when I visit my react app on port `3000`.
`Error : NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.`
I dont understand why, its giving such error. The [docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/get-started) have not mentioned any other configuration.

Comment: Do you get any CORS errors on your frontend? Try to console log your error like this: console.log(JSON.stringify(error, null, 2)). Apollo errors usually have more information about the error. In your API, use try catch to get any errors that happened on your API side.